# AWS Elastic Beanstalk NPM failing. Need to add in the --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I am trying to use npm package that has a max verison of 18.0 and my EB instance is on 18.2. I want to update the npm install command to add the -- legacy peer deps flag. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file .npmrc with config

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```